# GBM MissingNode in R

Tags: r, gbm

I am playing with the GBM package in R :

```
library(gbm) 
gbmfit <- gbm( UVIndex ~ UVI + UVA + VIS + UVIVIS + UVIUVA + CosSZA +   ShadeTemp, data = df, distribution = "gaussian", n.trees = 1000, shrinkage = 0.1, cv.folds = 10)
pred <- predict(gbmfit, data = df , n.trees = 1)
pretty.gbm.tree(gbmfit,i.tree = 1)
```

gives me :

```
  SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight
  0        0  380.50000000        1         2           3       471.9606    214
  1       -1   -0.11805471       -1        -1          -1         0.0000    140
  2       -1    0.19417906       -1        -1          -1         0.0000     74
  3       -1   -0.01008602       -1        -1          -1         0.0000    214

   Prediction
 0 -0.01008602
 1 -0.11805471
 2  0.19417906
 3 -0.01008602
```

When I look at a scatterplot of pred versus UVI, I see indeed a split of around 380 with two terminal values of 2.717099 and 3.029333. 
(1)How do I reconcile those terminal values with the parameters of the tree ? I should be able to derive them from SplitCodePred, but I don't see the connection
(2) Is it normal to have a missing node even if my data has no missing value ?
(3) I am confused with Weight ("the total number of observations in that node"). How come there is a weight of 214 for Node 3, although there is no missing data ?

Thanks a lot,

Roland

Comment: In order for us to understand what you are asking (and I think it it is really not a coding Q but rather a methodology question anyway) you would need to post code and data; neither of which can be seen.

Comment: I got it .. I was missing the constant, which is stored in gbmfit$initF ..  I'm still confused about (2) and (3)

Answer (score 0):

2) Yes it is normal to have missing node even if data doesn't have any missing values. Value of missing node will be the weighted average of values of other nodes

Example for a tree of depth 1 in case of no missing data or missing values < min obs value of missing node will be weighted average of value of your left and right nodes

3)Weight of missing node in this case(no missing values in data) will be the weight of parent node